# Can't Ping Paticular Windows Machine to Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a small server using a raspberry pi. I have it set up with wired internet access. I can confirm that on the pi I can ping google, a windows laptop, and a Debian laptop.

However cannot ping my main windows desktop. In addition, on the desktop itself I can ping the Debian laptop but not the pi. On the windows laptop I can ping the pi, the Debian laptop but not the desktop.

The error I get is: "Destination host unreachable."

Overall I would like to be able to SSH into the pi (I have enabled the SSH interface/service and can get into it from the laptops but not the desktop).

Both laptops are on wifi while the pi and the desktop are wired.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

After some trial and error I found that I could only ping devices from wired connections that were on wireless. I took a laptop and on wifi was able to ping the pi and desktop but when wired it was not able to ping either (with the same error as above).

Answer (score 0):

OK after some more searching around after my update above I found a dd-wrt thread that confirmed this was a bug in the firmware. The form post is [here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=152738&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=45&sid=7416022208c261d660d7b98c39bb64fc).

Furthermore there is a SuperUser post already on this topic [here](https://superuser.com/questions/642517/dd-wrt-cannot-see-client-when-using-wired-ethernet#810698).