# Unable to access local server via ethernet but can access via WiFi

Tags: networking, router, ssh, dd-wrt

Thank you in advance for your help!

As the title states, I have a local server running dietpi on a raspberry pi 4. I am able to SSH access it through my computer and phone when connected to my router via WiFi. But when I try to access the server through my computer connected via ethernet but not via WiFi, the server is not found. I confirmed this though using Angry IP scanner and it detects all the other devices on the network but not the server. Here is a list of things I've tried so far:

- Restarting my computer and the Raspberry Pi
- Checking the DNS of both my computer and Raspberry Pi (they're both on automatic from the router)
- Check my router settings to make sure both are being seen, they are (using DD-WRT for my router)
- Lots of Google searching...

I'm really out of ideas and could really use some help!

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Pi via IP address?  What happened?  Have you tried pinging its IP?   What happens if you connect to the Pi and then ping/traceroute to IPs connected to your LAN?

Comment: Hello. thanks for your response! I have tried pinging the ip address. works fine when connected to WiFi but no response when using just ethernet. I'm able to trace via WiFi but not via ethernet. it's as if the Pi doesn't exist when not connected to WiFi...

Comment: (How) is the Pi getting its IP address for ethernet?   If its statically assigned or the Pi is not actually getting an address, maybe the network cable or switch port is faulty?

Comment: the Pi is getting its IP address from the router. I actually found the solution based on your comment. there was a problem with the router itself. I've posted my solution below. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after hours and hours of google searching.. the router (DD-WRT) has a known issue with the LAN ports not talking to each other.. the fix was to make a virtual LAN so that they can talk to each other. in the command line you would type in the following:

```
swconfig dev eth0 set reset 1;
swconfig dev eth0 set enable_vlan 1
swconfig dev eth0 vlan 0 set ports '0 1 2 3 4'
swconfig dev eth0 set apply 1
```

[here](https://superuser.com/questions/642517/dd-wrt-cannot-see-client-when-using-wired-ethernet) is the source of the fix