# Cant access http local server through ethernet connection but can access through wifi

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I've got a local http server which is accessible through wifi connection but not accessible through an ethernet connection, i've found another user which had the same problem, but i cant test the solution, since it implies to use the command "swconfig" for setting up a VLAN, and repo in the AUR seems to be dead.

Source: [Unable to access local server via ethernet but can access via WiFi](https://superuser.com/questions/1633686/unable-to-access-local-server-via-ethernet-but-can-access-via-wifi)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is your WiFi connection done with the same router as you use for Ethernet? What model is the router?

Comment: Yes it is the same router, the route is a Technicolor CGA4233TCH3, im from Argentina if that helps

Comment: Some routers separate the wired and wifi networks, sometimes they have a setting to enable/disable this. What is the IP range and mask of the wired and wireless networks? Can other services communicate across the wired/wireless networks?

Comment: My knowledge about networking is pretty limited to be fair, my answer to what i interpreted with your question is that my PC (ethernet connection) local ip is 192.168.0.66
and my http server (wifi) is 192.168.0.243, they seem to be under the same type of address, if that answers your question. I can even ping my server from my pc.

Comment: Well, just found out that the problem is not that its wired or wireless the attempt to connect, but that im connecting from linux, rather than from windows. I have a dual boot setup in my main pc, and tried to access my web from Arch Linux and no response, tried from windows, and everything seems fine... also i have checked the firewall in linux and just cant get it to work